# How do export these data separated by multiple columns in a single row into .csv or .xls using Python in BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, excel, csv, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I currently have this data stored as the `result` variable.

```
['Draw Date:']
['Draw Date:']
['']
['']
['']
['Draw Date:  2019-01-15']
['']
['Perdana Lottery']
[]
['F', '2771', 'M', '0133', 'A', '6215']
[]
['A', '----', 'B', '1859', 'C', '3006', 'D', '3327']
['E', '5699', 'F', '----', 'G', '1123', 'H', '9193']
['I', '9076', 'J', '0573', 'K', '0950', 'L', '7258']
['', 'M', '-----', '', '', '']
['N', '1226', 'O', '0565', 'P', '1563', 'Q', '1420']
['R', '5265', 'S', '9345', 'T', '0483', 'U', '0933']
['', 'V', '6468', 'W', '3247', '']
['']
['']
['']
['']
```

I want to export this data into a table either in .csv or .xls format like this:

```
+------------+----------+----------+----------+----------+-------------+
| Date       | First    | Second   | Third    | Special  | Consolation |
+------------+---+------+---+------+---+------+---+------+---+---------+
| 2019-01-15 | F | 2771 | M | 0133 | A | 6215 | A | ---- | N | 1226    |
|            |   |      |   |      |   |      | B | 1859 | O | 0565    |
|            |   |      |   |      |   |      | C | 3006 | P | 1563    |
|            |   |      |   |      |   |      | ... etc  | ... etc     |
+------------+---+------+---+------+---+------+----------+-------------+
```

... etc means the remaining data from the above result variable. I didn't write it out here to avoid clutter.

So, which modules should I use and how to do it? Please note that, I'm a total Python newbie. I only know some PHP stuff but honestly I'm starting to love py.

Comment: if possible, share the code that you used to obtain this result. Being able to see explicitly what the `result` looks like/stores the data, could help. Is the `result` a list of the lists you posted?

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your reply. I truly appreciate it. The above data is exactly what stored in the result variable. How I got the data is not important right now because my problem is I just need to export them to csv in the above table format.

Comment: Yes I understand that, but by seeing how it's scraped, it might be possible to a) scrape and store that right into a table, as opposed to storing it as `result`, and then trying to manipulate it. Or b) see how it's explicitly stored. I still don't know how it's stored as a whole., as the data presented above, you can't convert that to a csv, or actually do anything with unless we know how that's stored. I have no idea of the structure and datatype of `result` as a whole, which by seeing how it's scraped, could clarify that. if you do `print (result)`, what does it show?

Comment: or is `result` a dataframe?

Comment: I'm sorry. What you said does make sense now. Here's the code: `soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(response, 'lxml')`

`num = 0`
`for tables in soup.select("table tr"):`
`num+=1`
`data = [item.get_text(strip=True) for item in tables.select("td")]`
`print(data)`

Is it possible to a) scrape and store that right into a table? I'm not sure how to do this.

Comment: yes sometimes it is possible to scrape straight into a tabe if it has `<table>` tags. I'll show you in a moment. can you supply the url you are requesting from?

Comment: and this does help a bit. I see you're printing off the result after each iteration. So `data` gets overwritten...but how are you dumping that into your `result` variable

Comment: The result variable is actually that data variable. I changed the name here for easier to understand. Sorry for the confusion! This is the target source: http://perdana4d.com/result.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first issue is that you need to know where the split is between the prizes. Without seeing the `Special Prize` text, this would be difficult. An alternative approach would be to use `find_all()` to spot just `td` and `th` elements. The list comprehension additionally only adds non-empty cells. This will result in a single list containing all the data you need.

`cols` contains a list of the required columns. This is filled manually for the 1st, 2nd and 3rd prizes as these entries should be fixed. A loop is then used to add the corresponding letters and prizes to the last four columns.

The Python `groupby()` function can be used to group lists into sub groups delimited by the elements found in `split_on`.

```
from itertools import groupby, zip_longest, islice
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import csv


def grouper(iterable, n):
    "Collect data into fixed-length chunks or blocks"
    # grouper('ABCDEFG', 3, 'x') --> ABC DEF Gxx"
    args = [iter(iterable)] * n
    return zip(*args)


response = requests.get("http://perdana4d.com/resulten.php")
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'lxml') 
rows = [cell.get_text(strip=True) for cell in soup.find_all(['td', 'th']) if len(cell.get_text(strip=True))]
draw_date = rows[2].split(' ')[-1]
split_on = ['Special Prize', 'Consolation Prize']

cols = [
    ['Date', draw_date], 
    ['FirstL', rows[7]], 
    ['FirstP', rows[8]], 
    ['SecondL', rows[9]], 
    ['SecondP', rows[10]], 
    ['ThirdL', rows[11]], 
    ['ThirdP', rows[12]], 
    ['SpecialL'], 
    ['SpecialP'], 
    ['ConsolationL'], 
    ['ConsolationP']
    ]

col_l = islice(cols, 7, None, 2)
col_p = islice(cols, 8, None, 2)

for k, g in groupby(rows[13:], lambda x: x not in split_on):
    if k:
        l = next(col_l)
        p = next(col_p)

        for letter, prize in grouper(g, 2):
            l.append(letter)
            p.append(prize)

with open('output.csv', 'w', newline='') as f_output:
    csv.writer(f_output).writerows(zip_longest(*cols, fillvalue=''))
```

This would result in a CSV file having the following type of format when loaded into a spreadsheet package:

[image: CSV format]

There are quite a lot of Python techniques used here which will take a while to understand. `grouper` for example is one of the [itertools recipes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html?highlight=islice#itertools-recipes). `islice()` is a way of iterating over an object without needing to start at the first position.

The final output to a CSV file is done using Python's CSV library. This converts lists of rows into correctly formatted output rows. As the data is in column format, a trick is needed to transpose the list into a list of rows, this is done using `zip_longest()`.

It would probably help if you add print statements to the code to see what the data looks like.

Note, to save the data directly to Excel format (.xlsx) you would need to install another library, for example you could use [openpyxl](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) or [xlwt](https://xlwt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).